# java middleware webservices - exception handling

Tags: java

I usually see a code, which pretty much wraps with try block for the entire operation of a web service.  The reasoning is to take care of un-expected results.  What is the best way to convince programmers not to follow such styles?

Of course, we do want to provide meaningful message to the client.  How can we handle such situations?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, in webservice I catch only specific exceptions (meaningful for customer) which may be thrown from application services tier. I do it in order to translate exceptions to the appropriate response status codes, for example: 
IllegalArgumentException -> Status.BAD_REQUEST, 
CustomerNotFoundException -> Status.NOT_FOUND

For this purpose you can also use exception mappers; here is an example for Apache CXF:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/systests/jaxrs/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/jaxrs/security/SecurityExceptionMapper.java

All other (runtime) exceptions which are not mapped results in 500 status code, and that's fine in my opinion - it's an internal server error, most probably software bug or infrastructure issue (DB has turn off). You have stacktrace in your log files and have to react immediately instead of informing customer that in some circumstances, invocation of one of your internal methods results in ArrayIndexOutofBoundException :)